# JQuery field check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply want to check if the input from field and field1 is the same. but I'm not sure where my mistake is.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#f').validate({ 
        rules: {
            field: {
                nowhitespace: true, 
                minlength: 6,
                required: true
            },
            field11: {
                equalTo: "#field1",
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
        field: {
                required: "required",
                minlength: "min 6."
            },
            field11: {
                required: "required",
            equalTo: "same as field."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            javascript:document.f.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="f" action="/path/to/service" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="field">Field</label>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input class="field" class="pw" type='field' id="field" name='field' size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="field1">field 1</label>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input class="field" class="pw" type='field1' id="field1" name='field1' size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align="center">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Can anybody see my mistake? thx for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rules` like,

```
rules: {
        field: {
            nowhitespace: true,
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        },
        field11: {
            equalTo: "#field",// Use "#field" in place of "#field1" 
            required: true
        }
    },
```

Also add **id** in your **form tag** as you used **$('#f').validate({** like,

```
<form name="f" id="f" action="/path/to/service" method="POST">
```

Or try it without **id** like,

```
$('form[name="f"]').validate({
```

Read **[equalTo method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have the `equalTo` rule on `field` set to `#field1` - it will always be equal to itself. Secondly, in the rules you are setting `field11`, yet the actual name is `field1`. Try this instead:

```
field1: {
    equalTo: "#field",
    required: true
}
```

Comment: oh sorry yeah thats not the problem. just a replace mistake because i changed the names.